# Vuejs and JS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, animation

I have a problem with my animation. I have two images in the one container, and the first image has z-index: 1, second image z-index: 2. First image added in tag (img src...) and has width 100%, and the second image as a background-image: url.. has width: 50%. When I hover my cursor on the container my second image changes the width overlapping the first image.
this process greatly slows down while changing the width (*https://www.loom.com/share/22975244e3254f75b83026551df55918*)
How can I make the animation like this, but smoothly?
The main code:

````
      if (this.$refs.beforeImage && this.$refs.trackContainer && this.$refs.trackLine && this.$refs.afterImage) {
        const cursorPositionX = event.pageX || (event.targetTouches && event.targetTouches[0].pageX)
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
        this.$refs.beforeImage.style.transition = null

        const trackContainerRect = this.$refs.trackContainer.getBoundingClientRect()
        const afterImageRect = this.$refs.afterImage.getBoundingClientRect()

        this.beforeImageWidth = ((cursorPositionX - afterImageRect.left) / this.$refs.afterImage.offsetWidth) * 100

        this.$refs.beforeImage.style.width = `${this.beforeImageWidth}%`
        if (this.beforeImageWidth > 100) this.$refs.beforeImage.style.width = '100%'
        if (this.beforeImageWidth < 0) this.$refs.beforeImage.style.width = '0%'
      }
    }```
````

Comment: Would just doing a pure CSS animation on the hover be useful rather than invoking JS to change the width?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I should change the width of the background image depending on the cursor position

Comment: You should still be able to have a smooth transition I think. Have you got a transition set on the element with the background image? Perhaps you could show us the relevant CSS and HTML structure.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use img-comparison-slider for my Vue project. I think it'll solve my problem. The component template and styles are too large, therefore I didn't paste them here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, I understood, I solved my problem by using the img-comparison-slider and how can I close this question? Can I just delete it?